# SSH push to Bitbucket using generated keys on Windows 7

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I follow documentation on Bitbucket site and would like to push existing project to remote repository by ssh. I perfomed next steps in CMD:

1. I generated public and private key using puttygen
2. Added private key using **pageant**
3. Added ssh config file inside ~/.ssh
4. Added public key to bitbucket

When I try to execute:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

I get stacktrace:

```
Enter passphrase for key 'k:\path\private_work_key.ppk':
Enter passphrase for key 'k:\path\private_work_key.ppk':
Enter passphrase for key 'k:\path\private_work_key.ppk':
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I even added the public key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , but the problem remains.

Please, Could someone explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The following scenario worked for me,

First add the key to your ssh agent,

```
ssh-add path/to/your/privatekey
```

and then, start the ssh-agent

```
ssh-agent
```

Now try pushing your project into your repository.

Comment: I perfomed this step: Added private key using pageant (an SSH authentication agent for PuTTY)

Comment: Can you please try `ssh-add -l`, and see whether your ssh key is been added to the ssh-agent?

Comment: It looks quite strange, in my opinion, that one ssh-agent doesn't see identity was added by other ssh-agent (default for GitBush). Also I had problems with format of my private. I had private key in .ppk format and always got exception connected with bad pass phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with "Permission denied (publickey)" with WIN7x64. Here is a short list to get it working, most important being the plink.exe usage!

1) Keypair creation using PuttyGen

2) Store public key to Bitbucket (Manage account / SSH Keys)

3) Change used BitBucket repository to use SSH authentication

4) Use Windows Pageant as a SSH authentication agent

5) Define remote git repository to use SSH authentication (git remote add  git@bitbucket.org :< accountname>/< reponame>.git)

6) Define GIT_SSH=plink.exe as a Windows shell variable. Now git push/pull/etc commands are passing the SSH authorization